# Unity - infinite spawn issue

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I almost have my game ready, I want to create an infinite number of 2D squares for my 2D game. However, the following code I used does not work to spawn a single square infinitely.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] locationsToSpawn;
    private float counter = 0;
    [SerializeField]
    string[] listOfPossibleTags;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject[] objectToSpawn;
    [SerializeField]
    float timeBetweenSpawns = 3.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        locationsToSpawn = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SpawnLocation");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        if (counter > timeBetweenSpawns)
        {
            GameObject spawnedObject;
            spawnedObject = Instantiate(objectToSpawn[Random.Range(0, objectToSpawn.Length)], locationsToSpawn[Random.Range(0, locationsToSpawn.Length)].transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            spawnedObject.gameObject.tag = listOfPossibleTags[Random.Range(0, listOfPossibleTags.Length)];
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, my game looks like the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahElg.png)

So, what can I do to create an infinite number of squares falling? I'm very close to finishing the game.

Comment: In what way does your code fail? Which parts are running as expected, and what's the incorrect behaviour you're observing? Please provide more detail, as we cannot run the code ourselves to find out.

Comment: Serlite is correct you need to provide more information. The code looks like it should spawn gameobjects. However, I'm going to guess that they are spawning on top of eachother. What is the value of objectToSpawn.Length and locationsToSpawn.Length when you debug?

Comment: I want to make an avoider game on Unity. When I insert the spawner code in the square object. The square is not spawing.

Comment: The square doesn't spawn.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're populating `objectToSpawn` in your screenshot...so it has no objects to choose from to supply to `Instantiate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided in your comments you are putting a script on a gameobject that doesn't exist in your scene. If there is no instance of your game object in the game your script will never run. Put the script on something else that makes sense and it will run.

When trying to figure out whats wrong with your code use the debugger. You will be able to find your problems much easier!